# Can't start Oowriter

Tags: ubuntu-10.10

I have some problems to start Open Office on Ubuntu 10.10. I've tried to start it by menu and by terminal (oowriter). Both ways are not working.

It's confusing to see that starting OpenOffice by typing ooffice in the terminal is working fine. So that's a workaround for me to use the OpenOffice Writer.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Probably belongs to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on askubuntu.com. Problem is solved.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/15456/cant-start-oowriter